# Is "join" slower in 3.x?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I was just messing around when I came across this quirk. And I wanted to make sure I am not crazy.

The following code (works in 2.x and 3.x):

```
from timeit import timeit
print ('gen: %s' % timeit('"-".join(str(n) for n in range(1000))', number=10000))
print ('list: %s' % timeit('"-".join([str(n) for n in range(1000)])', number=10000))
```

Doing 3 runs on each version, same machine.

*note:* I grouped the timings on the same line to save space here.

On my Python 2.7.5:

```
gen: 2.37875941643, 2.44095773486, 2.41718937347
list: 2.1132466183, 2.12248106441, 2.11737128131
```

On my Python 3.3.2:

```
gen: 3.8801268438439718, 3.9939604983350185, 4.166233972077624
list: 2.976764740845537, 3.0062614747229555, 3.0734980312273894
```

I wonder why this is.... Might it have something to do with how strings are implemented?

---

**EDIT:** I did it again without using `range()` since that has also changed slightly from 2.x to 3.x Instead I use the new code below:

```
from timeit import timeit
print ('gen: %s' % timeit('"-".join(str(n) for n in (1, 2, 3))', number=1000000))
print ('list: %s' % timeit('"-".join([str(n) for n in (1, 2, 3)])', number=1000000))
```

The Timing for Python 2.7.5:

```
gen: 2.13911803683, 2.16418448199, 2.13403650485
list: 0.797961223325,  0.767758578433, 0.803272800119
```

The Timing for Python 3.3.2:

```
gen: 2.8188347625218486, 2.882846655874985, 3.0317612259663718
list: 1.3590610502957934, 1.4878876089869366, 1.4978070529462615
```

---

**EDIT2:** It seems there were some more things throwing off the calculation, so I tried bringing it down to a bare-minimum.

New Code:

```
from timeit import timeit
print ('gen: %s' % timeit('"".join(n for n in ("1", "2", "3"))', number=1000000))
print ('list: %s' % timeit('"".join([n for n in ("1", "2", "3")])', number=1000000))
```

Timing Python 2.7.5:

```
gen: 1.47699698704, 1.46120314534, 1.48290697384
list: 0.323474182882, 0.301259632897, 0.323756694047
```

Timing Python 3.3.2:

```
gen: 1.633002954259608, 1.6049987598860562, 1.6109927662465935
list: 0.5621341113519589, 0.5789849850819431, 0.5619928557696119
```

---

The difference is clear, it is faster in 2.x and slower in 3.x And I am curious as to why...

Comment: In Python 3, `range` behaves like the former `xrange`. Python 2 may be caching the explicitly generated list, providing the observed speed-up. (This also would explain why the list version is faster than the generator version in both 2 and 3.)

Comment: http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#performance

Comment: @chepner You have a point there. I tried it again using `"x"*1000` instead of the range functions. And still 2.x is faster.

Comment: Another change is that `"-"` in python 2 is a byte string, and in python 3 a unicode string. Could you check the difference in timings accounting for that?

Comment: @liori yes. I will make a big change.... lets try this again being a bit smarter :)

Comment: try to compare bytes in both version, Unicode strings in both version e.g. for bytes: `python -mtimeit -s'L=(b"1", b"2", b"3")*100' 'b"".join(L)'`

Comment: liori is right. If you try to explicitly use u"" literals in your new code then difference will disappear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't worked on python3.3 yet. All these I have stated below is based on observation.

I used python disassembler for following code in python 3.3 and python 2.7.3.

```
s = """
''.join([n for n in ('1', '2', '3')])
"""
```

I found there are changes in the upcodes.

Python 2.7.3

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win
32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dis
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> s = """
... ''.join([n for n in ('1', '2', '3')])
... """
>>> timeit(s, number=100000)
0.08443676085287867
>>>
>>>
>>> c = compile(s, '<string>', 'exec')
>>> dis.dis(c)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               0 ('')
              3 LOAD_ATTR                0 (join)
              6 BUILD_LIST               0
              9 LOAD_CONST               5 (('1', '2', '3'))
             12 GET_ITER
        >>   13 FOR_ITER                12 (to 28)
             16 STORE_NAME               1 (n)
             19 LOAD_NAME                1 (n)
             22 LIST_APPEND              2
             25 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           13
        >>   28 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             31 POP_TOP
             32 LOAD_CONST               4 (None)
             35 RETURN_VALUE
>>>
```

python 3.3

```
Python 3.3.0 (v3.3.0:bd8afb90ebf2, Sep 29 2012, 10:55:48) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (In
tel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dis
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> s = """
... ''.join([n for n in ('1', '2', '3')])
... """
>>> timeit(s, number=100000)
0.13603410021487614
>>>
>>>
>>> c = compile(s, '<string>', 'exec')
>>> dis.dis(c)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               0 ('')
              3 LOAD_ATTR                0 (join)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object <listcomp> at 0x01F70BB
0, file "<string>", line 2>)
              9 LOAD_CONST               2 ('<listcomp>')
             12 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
             15 LOAD_CONST               7 (('1', '2', '3'))
             18 GET_ITER
             19 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             22 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             25 POP_TOP
             26 LOAD_CONST               6 (None)
             29 RETURN_VALUE
>>>
```

From the upcodes I got that it was list comprehension that had changed so i checked for list comprehension in both version

Python 2.7.3

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win
32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
>>>
>>>
>>> import dis
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> s = """
... [i for i in ('1', '2', '3')]
... """
>>> timeit(s, number=100000)
0.059500395456104374
>>> c = compile(s, '<string>', 'exec')
>>> dis.dis(c)
  2           0 BUILD_LIST               0
              3 LOAD_CONST               4 (('1', '2', '3'))
              6 GET_ITER
        >>    7 FOR_ITER                12 (to 22)
             10 STORE_NAME               0 (i)
             13 LOAD_NAME                0 (i)
             16 LIST_APPEND              2
             19 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            7
        >>   22 POP_TOP
             23 LOAD_CONST               3 (None)
             26 RETURN_VALUE
>>>
```

python 3.3

```
Python 3.3.0 (v3.3.0:bd8afb90ebf2, Sep 29 2012, 10:55:48) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (In
tel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
>>>
>>>
>>> import dis
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> s = """
... [i for i in ('1', '2', '3')]
... """
>>> timeit(s, number=100000)
0.09876976988887567
>>> c = compile(s, '<string>', 'exec')
>>> dis.dis(c)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (<code object <listcomp> at 0x01FF0BB
0, file "<string>", line 2>)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 ('<listcomp>')
              6 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
              9 LOAD_CONST               6 (('1', '2', '3'))
             12 GET_ITER
             13 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             16 POP_TOP
             17 LOAD_CONST               5 (None)
             20 RETURN_VALUE
>>>
```

I haven't worked with python3 or checked the changes. It seems like the list comprehension implementation has been changed. In python3.3 there is MAKE_FUNCTION and CALL_FUNCTION. (Now in python2.7 call to a function is costly. I am not sure whether in python3.3 call to function still costly or not. if that is case then that could add some time.)

Answer (score 1):

You're not comparing apples to apples.

In Python 2, `str` is what is called `bytes` in Python 3 (almost).

In Python 3, `str` is what is called `unicode` in Python 2.

Comment: So maybe profiling 2.x `str` to 3.x `bytes`, and 2.x `unicode` to 3.x `str` might be interesting.  It would be potentially interesting if those two showed different performance changes.